# Adding multiheaders to listview

Tags: android, listview

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(position == 0 || position == 2 || 
            position == 6 || position == 9 || position == 12 || position == 14)
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_header_title);
            txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
            convertView.setOnClickListener(null);
            convertView.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            convertView.setLongClickable(false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    else
    {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      //  TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        try
        {
            imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon()); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
    /*    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }*/
    }  
    return convertView;
}
```

I added that , into my adapter...  however problem is navigation drawer is screwing things up..
suddenly one row goes over the other..and suddenly on scroll the bottom row is on top etc.

I want to fix this issue, I only have that worth of note in my adapter class. inside my navigation drawer I just call the listview and attach adapter to it..

Why should on scroll below or top screen this occur?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout  [stickylistheaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library.